# Me piden que compare dos números enteros y poner un mensaje si terminan por el mismo número o distinto (Esto me lo piden hacer con if y else,)

Tags: números-enteros

**Escribe un programa en C que pida dos números enteros al usuario y compruebe si ambos terminan con el mismo dígito.**

Example 1:

Enter number 1: 5362
Enter number 2: 646
5362 and 646 do not end with the same digit.
Example 2:

Enter number 1: 46
Enter number 2: 646
46 and 646 end with the same digit.

Comment: explora comparaciones con el modulo 10 de cada numero